# Testcontainers' shaded dependencies

Tags: testcontainers

Testcontainers bundles several dependencies that are useful and that I would otherwise add to my pom.xml explicitly. They are labeled as "shaded", like e.g. `org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.Awaitility.await`.

Is it best practice to use these "shaded" dependencies or should I rather add them explicitly to my pom.xml?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should not use the shaded dependencies of a library (this is also the case for Testcontainers in particular), since I'd say they are not part of the public API and might be subject to change.

(Disclaimer: I am a TC maintainer)